# Proper way to print class names in log entries

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

Think I figured out a decent amount of Serilog to use in my application. However, I would like to "enrich" the log with `classnames` and etc. (HTTP methods in future). Registered a global instance of `Logger` object in Autofac and calling it in other classes, but the lines written to log file are being truncated or overwritten. Please help in suggesting a proper way of printing classnames. Here's my code,

**ZLogger.cs** (stripped out validations, try/catch, etc.)

```
public class ZLogger
{
    public Serilog.ILogger Logger
    {
        get
        {
            Serilog.ILogger logger = null;
            if (logger == null)
            {
                logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Destructure.ByTransforming<MySqlConnectionInfo>(
                    conn => new {
                        DatabaseName = conn.DatabaseName,
                        Hostname = conn.Hostname,
                        IPAddress = conn.HostIPAddress,
                        Username = conn.Username,
                        Password = "**********"
                    })
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo.Console(
                    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} | [{SourceContext}] | [{Level:u4}] | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose,
                    theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Colored)
                .WriteTo.File(
                    "../logs/logFile.log",
                    outputTemplate: "{UserInfo} | {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} | [{SourceContext}] | [{Level:u4}] | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.With(new UserInfoEnricher())
                .CreateLogger();
            }
            return logger;
        }
    }

    public ILogger GetCurrentClassLogger<T>()
    {
        return Logger.ForContext<T>();
    }
}
```

**ReadConfig.cs** (stripped out validations, try/catch, etc.)

```
public class ReadConfig
{
    public ILogger Logger;

    public ReadConfig(ZLogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger.GetCurrentClassLogger<ReadConfig>();
    }

    public T GetConfig<T>(string configFileName)
    {
        T config = default(T);

        var rootDir = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        var configFile = Directory.GetFiles(rootDir.FullName, configFileName);

        Logger.Information("Reading information from - \"{file}\"", configFile);
        var jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(configFile[0], Encoding.UTF8);
        config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonContent);
        Logger.Information("Parsed Config: {@config}", config);

        return config;
    }
}
```

**IoCBuilder.cs** (Autofac Builder)

```
public class IoCBuilder : Module
{
    ILogger Logger;

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        MySqlConnectionInfo mySqlConnection = null;
        var zlogger = new ZLogger();
        Logger = zlogger.GetCurrentClassLogger<IoCBuilder>();
        Logger.Debug("Registering dependancies ...");

        Logger.Debug("Reading Global Config ...");
        var readConfig = new ReadConfig(zlogger);
        var globalConfig = readConfig.GetConfig<GlobalConfig>("globalconfig.json");

        if (globalConfig.Environment == RunEnvironment.Production)
        {
            Logger.Debug("SQL Connection Information for {env}", globalConfig.Environment);
            mySqlConnection = globalConfig.MySqlConnectionInfo.FirstOrDefault(conn => conn.Name == "prod-master");
            Logger.Debug("Selected {@sqlconn}", mySqlConnection);
        }
        else
        {
            mySqlConnection = globalConfig.MySqlConnectionInfo.FirstOrDefault(conn => conn.Name == "dev-master");
            Logger.Debug("Selected {@sqlconn}", mySqlConnection);
        }

        // Registrations
        builder.RegisterInstance(zlogger).As<ZLogger>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterInstance(mySqlConnection).As<MySqlConnectionInfo>();
    }
}
```

And here's the log, 
**Console**

```
2018-03-05 21:33:08.331 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | Registering dependancies ...
2018-03-05 21:33:08.470 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | Reading Global Config ...
2018-03-05 21:33:10.530 | [Core.Config.ReadConfig] | [INFO] | Reading information from - "globalconfig.json"
2018-03-05 21:33:11.095 | [Core.Config.ReadConfig] | [INFO] | Parsed Config: {"Environment": "Production", "RedisConnectionInfo": [{"Name": "metadata", "Hostname": "localhost", "Port": 6379, "DbNumber": 0, "$type": "RedisConnectionInfo"}, {...}
2018-03-05 21:33:11.109 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | SQL Connection Information for Production
2018-03-05 21:33:11.113 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | Selected {"DatabaseName": "***", "Hostname": "***", "IPAddress": "**", "Username": "**", "Password": "**********"}
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 0 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 1 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 2 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 3 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.169 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 4 - Hello Serilog
```

**Log file**

```
2018-03-05 21:33:08.331 -05:00 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | Registering dependancies ...
2018-03-05 21:33:08.470 -05:00 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | Reading Global Config ...
2018-03-05 21:33:11.109 -05:00 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | SQL Connection Information for "Production"
2018-03-05 21:33:11.113 -05:00 | [Core.IoCBuilder] | [DBUG] | Selected {"DatabaseName": "***", "Hostname": "***", "IPAddress": "**", "Username": "**", "Password": "**********"}
":"localhost","Port":6379,"DbNumber":0,"$type":"RedisConnectionInfo"},{...}
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 -05:00 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 0 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 -05:00 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 1 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 -05:00 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 2 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.168 -05:00 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 3 - Hello Serilog
2018-03-05 21:33:11.169 -05:00 | [test.Program] | [WARN] | 4 - Hello Serilog
```

Notice the lines 3 & 4 in log file, they are not in order. Think `logger.GetCurrentClassLogger<T>()` is the culprit as that's being `new'd` up in every class and thus creating a new logger, which could be causing race conditions when writing to log file.

Does anyone know how to properly implement this? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

(Sorry for the long post, thought it would be useful to include as many details as possible!)

Answer (score 0):

It was silly on my part :D. Had to declare `logger` as private field outside the `Logger` property in `Zlogger.cs` class, and problem solved!!

**Working code:**

```
public class ZLogger
{

  Serilog.ILogger logger = null; // >>>>>> Had to move this out of Property get method <<<<<

  public Serilog.ILogger Logger
  {
      get
      {

          if (logger == null)
          {
              logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .Destructure.ByTransforming<MySqlConnectionInfo>(
                ....
```

Thank you @nblumhardt :)